# Concerning RAII: How to prevent errors caused by accidentally creating a temporary?

Tags: c++

A while age a colleague told me he spent lot of time debugging a race condition. The culprit turned out to be something like this:

```
void foo()
{
    ScopedLock(this->mutex); // Oops, should have been a named object.
                             // Edit: added the "this->" to fix compilation issue.
    // ....
}
```

In order to prevent situation from happening again he created the following macro after the definition of the ScopedLock class:

```
#define ScopedLock(...) Error_You_should_create_a_named_object;
```

This patch works fine.

Does anyone know any other interesting techniques to prevent this problem?

Comment: "This patch works fine" - up to the point where you start using namespaces.

Comment: @Steve: It will work fine with namespaces as well, as long as you don't have anything named `ScopedLock` in another namespace.  The macro will still work namespace-qualified (since it produces an error anyway).

Comment: @Jeremiah: the sole purpose of namespaces is to allow you to have something named `ScopedLock` in another namespace. Or specifically, to write code so that you don't care whether or not someone else likes the look of the name `ScopedLock` for their class (function, or global variable).

Comment: @Steve: Yes, that's true, and the macro will break having anything named `ScopedLock` in another namespace.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914861/disallowing-creation-of-the-temporary-objects which may or may not be a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to define a macro, I'd probably rather define this one:

```
#define GET_SCOPED_LOCK(name, mtx) ScopedLock name(mtx)
```

and stop creating objects other than via the macro.

Then rename `ScopedLock` to `ThisClassNameShouldNotAppearInUserCode` if that helps.

Comment: You could do with the "name" in the Macro. If it's a scope lock, you won't have two different objects in the same scope, so you can use a "constant" name without any worries regarding duplication.

Comment: @Computer Guru: You could always provide that too for convenience. It seems to me a bit intrusive to introduce a name into scope without the user really seeing what that name is (other than in the documentation). Using a compiler-generated unique name would deal with that, as long as the object provides no functions for the user to call. Also a bit awkward that if you want to lock two mutexes you have to introduce braces (and possibly deal with compiler warnings about shadowing the outer variable).

Answer (score 8):

You should use a static code analyser such as [Cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net). For the following code:

```
class a { };

void f() {
    a();
}
```

cppcheck generates the following output:

```
$ cppcheck test.cpp
Checking test.cpp...
[test.cpp:4]: (error) instance of "a" object destroyed immediately
```

There are a wide variety of other common coding errors also detected.

(I'm a fairly new contributor to Cppcheck. I found it a couple of months ago and it's been fantastic working with it.)

Comment: Thanks. I have experimented with Cppcheck a few times and found it useful. Perhaps I should work on integrating it with our build system.

Comment: @StackedCrooked: The Cppcheck development is proceeding at a pretty rapid pace. If you haven't tried it recently, definitely try it again.