# Strange compiler error when trying to create a temporary object

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

After I posting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158990/concerning-raii-how-to-prevent-errors-caused-by-accidentally-creating-a-temporar) I tried to reproduce the problem of accidental rvalue creation when creating a scoped RAII object. Now it appears that I can't reproduce it without compiler errors!

In the following code sample, in `Test::foo()` the second ScopedLock creation doesn't compile. The gcc compiler error seems totally wrong. Can anyone explain?

```
struct Mutex
{
    void lock() { }

    void unlock() { }
};


struct ScopedLock
{
    ScopedLock(Mutex & inMutex) : mMutex(inMutex)
    { mMutex.lock(); }

    ~ScopedLock()
    { mMutex.unlock(); }

private:
    ScopedLock(const ScopedLock&);
    ScopedLock& operator=(const ScopedLock&);

    Mutex mMutex;
};


struct Test
{
    void foo()
    {
        // Compiles fine
        ScopedLock lock(mMutex);

        // Error: no matching function for
        // call to ‘ScopedLock::ScopedLock()’
        ScopedLock(mMutex);
    }

    Mutex mMutex;
};
```

I'm using GCC 4.2.1 on Mac.

#### Update

I had a look at the original code and saw that the member was referenced through the `this` pointer:

```
ScopedLock(this->mMutex); // short-lived temporary and compiles fine
```

Comment: Heh, I wondered about this on your previous question... The syntax implies a function call, not a temporary object. You may wish to ask your co-worker if his situation wasn't a *bit* more involved than he made it out to be.

Comment: Yes, I'm definitely going to check it out tomorrow.

Comment: @Shog9 It turns out he used the following syntax: `ScopedLock(this->mutex);`. Which compiles fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two user declared constructors, so there is no compiler generated default one.

Yes,

```
Type (i);
```

is handled in the same way as

```
Type i;
```

Such parenthesis are useful in more complex declarations such as

```
Type (*i)();
```

to declare a pointer to a function returning a type.

Answer (score 0):

The message is telling you that ScopedLock doesn't have a default constructor, i.e. one that takes no arguments. If you declare a constructor that takes arguments, C++ won't create a default one for you.

Comment: GCC is correct that there is indeed no default constructor. However, the constructor that I'm calling is not the default one. It's the one that takes a `Mutex&` argument.

Comment: No, according to gcc you're creating a ScopedLock called mMutex. Add the () ctor, then call mMutex.lock() after the ScopedLock(mMutex) call, it'll complain that ScopedLock doesn't have a lock member function

Comment: @Erik, it seems you're right. Is GCC in the wrong here or is my code illegal?

Comment: Without reading through the standard, I think GCC is right. MSVC gives a corresponding error message.