# What's actually going on in this AnonymousClass(variable) declaration?

Tags: c++

Trying to compile:

```
class AnonymousClass
{
public:
    AnonymousClass(int x)
    {
    }
};


int main()
{
    int x;
    AnonymousClass(x);
    return 0;
}
```

generates errors from MSVC:

```
foo.cpp(13) : error C2371: 'x' : redefinition; different basic types
    foo.cpp(12) : see declaration of 'x'
foo.cpp(13) : error C2512: 'AnonymousClass' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

g++'s error messages are similar:

```
foo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cpp:13: error: conflicting declaration ‘AnonymousClass x’
foo.cpp:12: error: ‘x’ has a previous declaration as ‘int x’
foo.cpp:12: warning: unused variable ‘x’
```

It's easily fixable by giving the `AnonymousClass` object an explicit name, but what's going on here and why?  I presume that this is more declaration syntax weirdness (like the cases described in [Q10.2](http://web.archive.org/web/20141212201215/http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/empty-parens-in-object-decl.html) and [Q10.21](http://web.archive.org/web/20141209131838/http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/fn-decl-vs-obj-instantiation.html) of the comp.lang.C++ FAQ), but I'm not familiar with this one.

Comment: one of the similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159438/strange-compiler-error-when-trying-to-create-a-temporary-object

Comment: Ah, yes, parentheses clearly are legitimate around the symbol name as in the typical case of function pointer declarations.  Yay.

Comment: You can also prevent `AnonymousClass(x)` from being treated as a definition of `x` by forcing it to be a sub-expression. For example `(void) AnonymousClass(x);`. Syntactically there's no way this can be a definition, hence it's an expression statement that creates an object using the one-arg constructor then destroys it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155571/how-is-atmpvector-the-same-as-a-tmpvector

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
AnonymousClass(x);
```

It defines a variable `x` of type `AnonymousClass`. That is why you're getting redefinition error, because `x` is already declared as `int`.

The parentheses are *superfluous*. You can add even more braces like:

```
AnonymousClass(x);
AnonymousClass((x));
AnonymousClass(((x)));
AnonymousClass((((x))));
//and so on
```

All of them are same as:

```
AnonymousClass x;
```

Demo: http://www.ideone.com/QnRKH

---

You can use the syntax `A(x)` to create anonymous object, especially when calling a function:

```
int x = 10;
f(A(x));        //1 - () is needed
f(A((((x)))));  //2 - extra () are superfluous
```

Both line `1` and `2` call a function `f` passing an object of type `A` :

- http://www.ideone.com/ofbpR

But again, the *extra* parentheses are still superfluous at line `2`.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Is allowing parentheses around declared names useful for anything other than for declaring function pointers?

Comment: @jamesdlin: As I said,  parentheses are *superfluous* when declaring a variable. But they're NOT *superfluous* when declaring function pointers; its needed then.  `A (*x)()` has different meaning than `A *x()`. The former declares a function pointer, latter is a function declaration (prototype).

Comment: @Nawaz: My comment above asked if they're useful for anything *other* than for function pointers.

Comment: @jamesdlin: I think, the word *superfluous* explains that its not useful when declaring a variable. On the contrary, it adds confusion.

Comment: But they're not completely superfluous.  They're superfluous in my particular case, but as you mentioned, they're *not* superfluous for variables of function pointer type.  Are there any other cases?  It seems a little odd that the C standards committee allowed this weird syntax just for that one case.

Comment: @jamesdlin: But of course, you can use the syntax `A(x)` to create anonymous object, especially when calling a function:  `f(A(x))` and `f(A((x)))` both call `void f(A a);` passing an object of type `A` : http://www.ideone.com/ofbpR

Comment: @jamesdlin: the parens are also used for declaring array references and pointers. For example `AnonymousClass *ptr[3]` has a different type from `AnonymousClass (*ptr)[3]`. It's really not a case of allowing weird syntax for a special case -- there's a general syntax that happens to be weird with simple types (because it appears ambiguous with what it would mean in an expression, i.e. the construction of a temporary with 1 arg).

Comment: @Steve: +1. How come I forgot that. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

You're missing an actual name for your variable/object:

```
AnonymousClass myclass(x);
```

Instead of that you could as well write...

```
AnonymousClass (myclass)(x);
```

So your line of code results in this:

```
AnonymousClass (x);
```

Or more common:

```
AnonymousClass x;
```

Why it happens? Brackets are just there for logical grouping ("what belongs together?"). The only difference is, they're forced for arguments (i.e. you can't just write `AnonymousClass myclass x`).

Comment: They're more than just for grouping.  You can't just add parentheses willy-nilly.  Parentheses around types and parentheses with keywords have special meanings.  You can't add parentheses around keywords themselves and so forth.  Really I wanted to know why parentheses are allowed at all around the variable name in a declaration.

Comment: Adding parentheses around types is different cause this will be interpreted as a cast. Around keywords they won't make any sense, but around actual (variable names) they make sense for logical grouping (see Nawaz' answer; e.g. telling the compiler where the `*` belongs to).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such a mistake, just remember one rule: **If you declare an anonymous object with one argument, just place it into a pair of parentheses!**