# Anonymous object with one argument cannot be declared

Tags: c++

There is this code:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass(){}

    SomeClass(SomeClass& b){}

    SomeClass(SomeClass&b, SomeClass& c){}
};

int main()
{
    SomeClass a;
    SomeClass(); // works all right
    //SomeClass(a); error: redeclaration of ‘SomeClass a’
    SomeClass(a, a); // works all right
    return 0;
}
```

Anonymous object of SomeClass with 0 and 2 parameters can be declared, however it cannot be declared with only 1 argument. I assume that writing

```
SomeClass(a);
```

is the same as

```
SomeClass a;
```

How to create anonymous object with one argument?

Comment: @BoBTFish: No. He is creating a temporary object through functional-cast syntax, essentially. You _never_ call a constructor directly; not even the code you posted actually does that

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's actually going on in this AnonymousClass(variable) declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341951/whats-actually-going-on-in-this-anonymousclassvariable-declaration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct a temporary object in a statement of its own with something like:

```
(SomeClass)a;
```

or

```
(SomeClass(a));
```

As you've observed, the parentheses are needed to resolve the ambiguity between a declaration and an expression statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can create that anonymouse object as the following:

```
(SomeClass(a));
```

This resolves the ambiguity since it can't be a declaration of `a`.

```
(SomeClass a); // Error: this can't be a declaration because of the parentheses
               //        but what else should it be?
```

Answer (score 2):

In that context, the braces are superfluous, which means

```
SomeClass(a); //declaration of a
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
SomeClass a; //declaration of a
```

which is again equivalent to these:

```
SomeClass((a)));       //declaration of a
SomeClass(((a)));      //declaration of a
SomeClass((((a))));    //declaration of a
SomeClass(((((a)))));  //declaration of a
```

All of these declare a variable of name `a` and type `SomeClass`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you avoid the most vexing parse by writing code with the same effect as what you wanted to write, but that can't be parsed as a declaration.

Often, this is done by adding parentheses.

In this case `(SomeClass(a));` will do, or `(void) SomeClass(a);`

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct.

You simply cannot create a temporary object with a single constructor argument in a context where the same statement could be a declaration. The grammar makes it ambiguous (or, it *would* be ambiguous if the behaviour you're seeing weren't defined to take precedence).

Why not give the object a name, instead?

```
SomeClass obj(a);
```

Or, if you have a reason to want the object to be destroyed immediately (sometimes this is useful; e.g. a `boost::this_thread::interruption_point`, though that takes no arguments), you can still create a temporary but de-ambiguate the statement:

```
(SomeClass(a));    // the parens prevent this from being a declarative statement
```

In some scenarios you may also be able to use C-style casts:

```
(SomeClass)a;
```

But, hopefully, your `SomeClass` constructor is actually marked `explicit`, and we prefer not to use C-style casts anyway.

This problem doesn't arise in other contexts, ones in which a temporary might make more sense anyway:

```
std::cout << SomeClass(a);  // *can't* be a decl of a `SomeClass` called `a`
```

Comment: "Why not change when the object is destroyed, instead?" ;-p