# A constructor declarator can be surrounded by parentheses. Why?

Tags: c++

[[class.ctor]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor#1)

> Constructors do not have names. In a declaration of a constructor, the
>   declarator is a function declarator (8.3.5) of the form ptr-declarator
>   ( parameter-declaration-clause ) exception-specification<sub>opt</sub>
>   attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> where the ptr-declarator
>   consists solely of an id-expression, an optional
>   attribute-specifier-seq, and **optional surrounding parentheses**, and
>   the id-expression has one of the following forms: **...**

And yes, this compiles:

```
struct S{
    (S)() {}
};
```

But why is this allowed?

Comment: Probably because *all* ptr-declarators may include optional parentheses.

Comment: Do you mean where it is practical ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the constructor is a function, and most declarations can be surrounded by parentheses (even multiple):

```
// all are valid!
void ((a))(); // void a();
int (a); // int a;
struct S {
    (S)(); // constructors
    (~S)(); // destructors
};
```

See [Why does C++ allow us to surround the variable name in parentheses when declaring a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29675756/6936976) for why this is allowed. This syntax was probably extended to constructors when they were defined.