# Most vexing parse with array access

Tags: c++, c++03, most-vexing-parse

While looking at some C++03 code, I found an instance of the *most vexing parse* that confused me:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main(int, char** argv)
{
    std::stringstream ss(std::string(argv[0]));
}
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xF18aUKQ1Vh4niYa)

In the snippet above, `ss` is a declaration to a function that takes a `std::string*` and returns `std::stringstream`.

**How is `std::string(argv[0])` being parsed as `std::string*`?**

Intuitively I thought that `argv[0]` was unambiguously an access to `argv`.

Comment: This failed to compile for me with Visual Studio 2015 because `argv[0]` is apparently a 0 sized array of type `argv`. I can get the same result as you if I use `argv[1]`. Interesting question.

Comment: I think it's equivalent to `std::stringstream ss(std::string argv[]);` which is itself equivalent to `std::stringstream ss(std::string * argv);`.

Comment: I think there was this one guideline, _if it looks like a declaration it is one_. so like @FrançoisAndrieux wrote your instantiation from std::string isn't a  instantiation but instead a declaration for array of std:strings

Comment: [CppCon 2017: Louis Brandy “Curiously Recurring C++ Bugs at Facebook”](https://youtu.be/lkgszkPnV8g?t=30m22s)

The links is set to the correct time code. took me while to remember in which video i learned about that but perfectly fits what you have just encountered

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason is because in the context of a function declaration, the compiler will interpret `std::string(argv[0])` as `std::string argv[0]`, i.e. a *declaration* of a zero-sized array as the function parameter *named* `argv` (overshadowing the `argv` from `main`, as this is a different scope), which then is equivalent to a pointer by *array-to-pointer-decay*.

Therefore, `std::stringstream ss(std::string(argv[0]));` means the same as `std::stringstream ss(std::string* argv);`

Edit: As it got correctly annotaded in the comments, zero-sized array declarations are invalid in C++, rendering the program ill-formed. When compiling this code with `-pedantic` flags (GCC and clang), warnings will be issued. Visual Studio even produces a compilation error. For any other array index than 0, the argumentation above however still holds.

Comment: so the most vexing parse is even more evil than I always thought... it is not just "if it looks like a function declaration it is a function declaration" but also "if it looks like an invalid function declaration it is a function declaration"....omfg

Comment: @tobi303: Have a peek at the grammar. It defines arrays roughly as `type name_optional [ size_expression ]`, and there is no special grammar rule for expressions that evaluate to zero. Would be _very_ hard, though, as expression evaluation in C++ is Turing-complete.

Comment: @tobi303 it is not an invalid declaration, though. In C++, [a variable declaration is allowed to wrap the variable name in parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675601/). Ie `int(x)` is the same as `int x`. This is why `std::string(argv[0])` can be seen as `std::string argv[0]` in this context. Just remove `std::string` to avoid the MVP: `std::stringstream ss(argv[0]);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau arent 0 sized arrays invalid?

Comment: @tobi303 yes, but that doesn't change the fact that MVP would still parse it as a fixed-sized array (even if the size is illegal), and a fixed-sized array decays to a pointer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, got it. It just happens that `void foo(double x[0]){}` is fine, due to just another quirk of c++

Answer (score 7):

I believe this follows from the "declaration syntax is like expression syntax" principle, and the fact that "array" parameters are pointers.

The following array declarations are equivalent:

```
int x[1];
int (x)[1];
int (x[1]);
```

more or less because `x[a]`, `(x)[a]`, and `(x[a])` are equivalent expressions.

Thus,

```
std::stringstream ss(std::string(argv[0]))

                 <=>

std::stringstream ss(std::string argv[0])

                 <=>

std::stringstream ss(std::string* argv)
```