# Compiling error: missing argument in temporary object constructor

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, language-lawyer

When creating a temporary object in a scope, the compiler doesn't see the provided argument to the constructor and gives a compiling error.

As in the following example:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class csventry
{
public:
        csventry(std::ostream& ostream) :
                _ostream(ostream)
                {}

        ~csventry() 
                { _ostream << std::endl; }

        csventry& operator << (const std::string& value) {
                _ostream << ", ";
                _ostream << value;
                return *this;
        }

private:
        std::ostream& _ostream;
};

int main () 
{
        std::ostringstream log;

        { csventry(log) << "User Log-on:"; }
        { csventry(log); }
        { csventry(log) << "Summary:"; }

        std::cout<<log.str()<<std::endl;
}
```

I get this error.

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:29:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘csventry::csventry()’
  { csventry(log); }
                ^
main.cpp:7:2: note: candidate: csventry::csventry(std::ostream&)
  csventry(std::ostream& ostream) :
  ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:7:2: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp:4:7: note: candidate: constexpr csventry::csventry(const csventry&)
 class csventry
       ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:4:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Tried with gcc 7.3 and 5.4

It worked when I name the temporary object, `{ csventry entry(log); }`

Why does the compiler miss the provided argument?

Comment: I'm uncertain about what happens but I have a little work-around: [Live Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/957b107eea29ffa2). (I introduced a helper function.)

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675601/why-does-c-allow-us-to-surround-the-variable-name-in-parentheses-when-declarin

Comment: Btw why do you need to put temporaries into scope? If you would not you would catch the reason of the error sooner.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`csventry(log);` doesn't create a temporary object as you expected; parentheses are considered redundant, in fact it declares an object named `log` with type `csventry`, i.e. it's same as `csventry log;`. As the error message said, it fails because `csventry` doesn't have the default constructor.

As the workaround you can change it to `csventry{log};`.

[[stmt.ambig]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ambig#1):

(emphasis mine)

> There is an ambiguity in the grammar involving expression-statements and declarations: An expression-statement with a function-style explicit type conversion as its leftmost subexpression can be indistinguishable from a declaration where the first declarator starts with a (. **In those cases the statement is a declaration**.

Comment: Why is it interpreted in such way? Is it defined in standard?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen because you can use () in declaration, for example `int (*funcptr)();`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Quotes from standard added.

Comment: Ah, I see it now, didn't think about function pointers. And thanks for standard snippet! :)