# what's wrong with this anonymous constructor call?

Tags: c++

The following code compiles fine under GCC and MSVC:

```
#include <string>

class C
{
public:
   C(const std::string&) { }
};

void f()
{
    std::string s;
    const std::string& sr = s;
    C c = C(sr);
}
```

Furthermore, if I replace that (entire) last line with this, both compilers accept it:

`(C(sr));`

However, if I replace that last line with this:

`C(sr);`

Compilers report the following:

GCC:

> $ c++ --std=c++17 yo.cpp
> yo.cpp: In function ‘void f()’:
> yo.cpp:13:9: error: conflicting declaration ‘C sr’
> C(sr);
> ^
> yo.cpp:12:24: note: previous declaration as ‘const string& sr’
> const std::string& sr = s;

MSVC:

> cl /std:c++17 Source.cpp
> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27043 for x64
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
> Source.cpp
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xlocale(319): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
> Source.cpp(14): error C2040: 'sr': 'C' differs in levels of indirection from 'const std::string &'
> Source.cpp(14): error C2512: 'C': no appropriate default constructor available
> Source.cpp(3): note: see declaration of 'C'

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This has never compiled in c++. And `C(sr)` is not a constructor call, it's actually as if you wrote `C sr;`. Now you can see that it's a redeclaration, which is not allowed.

Comment: @cigien, sorry, see my latest edits. I did a bit more experimenting after hitting submit. (Also removed the note about C++17 after double-checking it.)

Comment: Yes, I see that. I've answered below.

Comment: The Slightly-Vexing Parse strikes again

Comment: @M.M, I can't find anything written about "Slightly Vexing Parse" anywhere. Is this name just oral tradition? I'd like to read more about it.

Comment: It's a play on "Most Vexing Parse" :) It's not an official term, it's used to describe situations such as this, where human beings see some code, and it *obviously* means something to them, but the compiler disagrees. There are a few examples of this nature, and depending on your familiarity with c++, they may be more or less vexing for you :)

Answer (score 4):

This statement:

```
C(sr);
```

is not calling a constructor. The syntax is actually a declaration of a variable named `sr` of type `C`, with additional redundant parentheses around the declarator `sr`.

Since `sr` has already been declared, you get an error.

On the other hand, in this statement:

```
(C(sr));
```

the expression `C(sr)` is actually parsed as the initialization of a `C` object, where `sr` is passed as an argument. The temporary `C` object that gets created is then destroyed at the end of the full expression.

Comment: `C{sr};` is another option. Technically it's not a constructor call, it's a request for creation of an object which may involve the constructor being called.  (e.g. in C++20 if `C` were an aggregate, then `(C(sr));` proceeds with aggregate initialization and there is no constructor call)

Comment: I don't hate many things about C++. I now hate this.


Comment: @KeithRussell I'm sorry to hear that, it is an unfortunate syntactical oddity. fwiw, use `{}` for objects, and `()` for function calls, and that'll reduce the chances of making these mistakes :)

Comment: @cigien until we get to objects where list initialization has different behaviour to parenthesized initialization from the same arguments... (e.g. `std::vector`)

Comment: @M.M Yes, but I think adding that to the answer would be a digression, and not very useful to explain the parsing issue. Is the edit better?

Comment: What ever was the use of allowing/ignoring parenthesis around the names of variables in declarations, I wonder?

Comment: @KeithRussell See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675601/why-does-c-allow-us-to-surround-the-variable-name-in-parentheses-when-declarin

Comment: Ah, thanks. So, it's to support the other awkward element of C declaration syntax: function pointers.  I wonder if there was a design choice they coulda made at the beginning to avoid both of these in one stroke.