# unsigned long long(10) fails to compile on clang and gcc

Tags: c++

The following code is rejected by both clang and gcc but accepted by msvc:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << unsigned long long(10);
}
```

The error is

> error: expected primary-expression before 'unsigned'

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4Yaoj4)

This should compile, right?

Comment: I am pretty sure you have to use parentheses around the c-style cast, as in ```std::cout << (unsigned long long)(10);```, or better practice to just use c++-style cast of ```std::cout << static_cast<unsigned long long>(10);```

Comment: @NikhilChatterjee I've tried parens around the whole expression and that didn't work so I thought it can't be parens, lol

Comment: @Timo You would need parenthesis around the *type*, not the *whole expression* (though, that is not a bad idea, either, when using C-style casting).

Comment: @RemyLebeau yeah I've read your answer, thank you :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, what you have shown should NOT compile.  See [Explicit type conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) on cppreference.com for details.

In a function-style cast, spaces are not allowed in the type name.  For such types, you would need to use a C-style or C++-style cast instead, eg:

```cpp
std::cout << ((unsigned long long)10);
or
std::cout << static_cast<unsigned long long>(10);
```

Otherwise, use a type alias instead, eg:

```cpp
using ull = unsigned long long; // C++11 and later
or
typedef unsigned long long ull; // pre-C++11

std::cout << ull(10);
```

Note, the [`<cstdint>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) header *may* have a `uint64_t` type you can use, eg:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

std::cout << uint64_t(10);
or
std::cout << ((uint64_t)10);
or
std::cout << static_cast<uint64_t>(10);
```

That being said, for integer literals, you can alternatively use the [`ULL` suffix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) (C++11 and later), eg:

```cpp
std::cout << 10ULL;
```

Comment: Hmm but variable declarations are ok. `unsigned long long (x);`. Why is casting different? Is there a parsing problem or is this just because?

Comment: @Timo in a variable declaration, `unsigned long long (x);` is treated the same as `unsigned long long x;`, all parenthesis around the variable name are ignored, so even something like `unsigned long long ((((x))));` is a valid declaration of `x`. See [Why does C++ allow us to surround the variable name in parentheses when declaring a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675601/)