# Possible to detect stack allocated object that isn't captured?

Tags: c++, raii

Is it possible to prevent or detect the following bug, in any way (static analysis), where the stack allocated object is not captured and goes out of scope on the same line that it was constructed?

```
Resource  resourceA, resourceB;

void someFunction()
{
    ScopedResourceBinder resourceBindA( resourceA );
    ScopedResourceBinder( resourceB ); // <--- BUG
}
```

The first `ScopedResourceBinder` is correct, but the second one doesn't do anything, since it immediately 'unbinds' right after it 'binds' (hypothetically speaking).

This is clearly a programmers error, but I have debugged this a few times now (for hours on a couple occassion) and it is extremely difficult to spot. Once you see it you think "ah that was a stupid one", but in practice, it is easy to make the mistake and the compiler is defenseless... or is it?

Background info: I work with a library that makes heavy use RAII class for pushing an popping state, for example OpenGL resources.  Managing the bindings with scope is a big improvement of manually calling bind() / unbind() functions, but the potential bug listed here comes up with this new pattern.

Comment: [Maybe of interest](http://stackoverflow.com/q/914861/596781)

Comment: My compiler generates an error for ScopedResourceBinder(resourceB); if ScopedResourceBinder doesn't have a default constructor defined. [This matches ideone's C++ 4.8.1 behavior.](http://ideone.com/3VApFF)

Comment: Create a plug-in for clang that catches this.  http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangPlugins.html

Answer (score 2):

`ScopedResourceBinder( resourceB );` is the same as `ScopedResourceBinder resourceB;`, i.e. it declares a named variable with name `resourceB`, calling the default constructor of `ScopedResourceBinder`.

This persists until the end of the function, however it is still a bug because it does not carry out your intent of binding to the variable `resourceB`.

To prevent this particular case you could make sure that `ScopedResourceBinder` does not have a default constructor.

Comment: In fact, it never binds at all, since it's default constructed.

Comment: Right, it is still a bug (although not in quite the same way that the OP had in mind!)

Comment: And this points out one way to avoid it -- make sure your scoped lock-like objects don't have a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In general coding practice, we should explicitly express our intent in the class definition itself.

For eg:

If we want to have singleton class, then all the constructors should be made private.

If we want to constructs an object with some variables, then only the required constructor should be exposed publicly, rest all should be mentioned as private.

In this manner we would be able to flag all wrong usage during compile time only.