# Is it possible to explicitly instantiate temporary variables in C++?

Tags: c++

Some people are warning that locks can be mis-used by writing:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mutex);
```

instead of the following correct statement:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
```

I.e. create an unnamed temporary variable instead of a local variable. The temporary variable would be destroyed immediately and unlock the mutex prematurely.

See for instance [gperftools (line 321-324) header](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/gperftools/+/master/src/base/simple_mutex.h):

```
// Catch bug where variable name is omitted, e.g. MutexLock (&mu);
#define MutexLock(x) COMPILE_ASSERT(0, mutex_lock_decl_missing_var_name)
#define ReaderMutexLock(x) COMPILE_ASSERT(0, rmutex_lock_decl_missing_var_name)
#define WriterMutexLock(x) COMPILE_ASSERT(0, wmutex_lock_decl_missing_var_name)
```

This macro is written to protect again such use cases.

But can it still happen? Apparently a recent enough GCC or clang will produce errors in this case:

```
#include <iostream>

class Mutex {};

class Lock {
public:
  explicit Lock(Mutex */* dummy */) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
  ~Lock() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  Mutex mutex;
  {
    Lock l(&mutex);
  }
  {
    Lock(&mutex); // This line does not compile.
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And the error:

```
g++ foo.cpp
foo.cpp:17:11: error: declaration of reference variable 'mutex' requires an initializer
    Lock(&mutex);
          ^~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Could someone exhibit a repro case where such a macro would catch a real bug? I could not come up with one so far.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914861/disallowing-creation-of-the-temporary-objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually being saved by the disambiguation rule for things-that-can-be-declarations (they are parsed as declarations, not expressions), coupled with the rule requiring references to be initialized.

It won't save you here:

```
std::mutex m;
int main(){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m); // m is a local default-constructed unique_lock
}
```

or here:

```
struct C { Mutex m; } c;
int main() {
    Lock(&c.m);  // Constructs and destroys a temporary lock.
 }
```

Comment: For the first example, it is very confusing that if the std::mutex is inside main if does not compile but if the mutex is outside it does. Could you elaborate about what kind of pattern are problematic here?

Comment: @ThomasMoulard `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m);` is exactly equivalent to `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> m;` since it's parsed as a declaration. It should be pretty obvious now why it doesn't compile if the mutex is inside `main`.